# Handling SQLException for Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to handle the exception when I delete a record where my KitID is referenced by other records in my Hardware table. I have set up the relationships in the SQL Server Express database.

The error I am receiving is

"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Hardware_Kit". The conflict occurred in database "C:\WEBSITES\GEOQ\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF", table "dbo.Hardware", column 'KitID'. The statement has been terminated."

I expect to receive that error but I am wondering why my code to handle the error is not working.

I have set up some breakpoints in the TRY and the CATCH. The SQL Statement executes just fine when there are no conflicts but when there is a conflict it will not go into the catch block at all.

I feel that I am missing something very trivial.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Controls_Control_Admin_Kit : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void KitListView_OnItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Kit] WHERE [KitID] = @KitID";
            SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            switch (SqlEx.Number)
            {
                case 547:
                    // Do something.
                    ErrorLabel.Text = "Error: There are hardware items associated with this Kit. <br />You must change the Kit field of each of the hardware items prior to deleting it. " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.google.com/search?q=Kits") + " that require changing";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually deleting the record in the try section.

`OnItemDeleting` triggers BEFORE an attempt is made to delete the record.

You need to handle the `OnItemDeleted` event.

The documentation here shows you how to handle an exception: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdeleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx